# Define double[,] as Datamember

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to  define double[,] as datamember ? 
If not, is there some way to define something that look like two dimensional array as datamember ?

Comment: how would you like to assign the datamember? paste some code here

Comment: this is the question .. if its possible because i try and i dont see that its can be done in the way i define all the other datamembers.

Comment: i'd like to help you but actually it's not clear how you'd like to use this datamember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember]
    double[][] JaggedArray { get; set; }

    public Data()
    {
        int count = 10;
        JaggedArray = new double[ count ][];
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            JaggedArray[ i ] = new double[ count ];
        }
    }
}
```